# MFMailComposeViewController taking ages to send email

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I'm building an app in which I need to attach and send multiple photos in an email. To accomplish this I save the photos to disk in the camera VC and access them in the viewDidLoad() of the email VC. I store them as .pngData() in a array and attach them in the MFMailComposeViewController using this code:

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Email")!])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Заявление")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("\(ProtocolText.text!)", isHTML: false)

    // unpacking images from array and attaching them to Email

    var dataName = 0
    for data in imageData {
        dataName += 1
        mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "\(dataName).png")
    }

    return mailComposerVC

}
```

These are my "save" and "get" methods:

```
func loadImage(fileName: String) -> UIImage? {

    let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory

    let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

    if let dirPath = paths.first {
        let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl.path)
        return image

    }

    return nil
}

    // Used in CameraViewController
func saveImage(imageName: String, image: UIImage) {


    guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }

    let fileName = imageName
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return }

    //Checks if file exists, removes it if so.
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
            print("Removed old image")
        } catch let removeError {
            print("couldn't remove file at path", removeError)
        }

    }

    do {
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch let error {
        print("error saving file with error", error)
    }

}
```

For some reason the images attach but the email takes at least 15 seconds to send. The "send" button just gets stuck. I don't know why. Please help.

Comment: How big are these images?   Also the code above has you saving the files as JPEG and attaching them as PNG.  Does it work any better with pngData instead of jpegData?

Comment: Thank you! Issue fixed. I believe it was super slow because of the file size. With a 0.75 compressionQuality the lag is significantly less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the weight of the image. One image used to weigh 6848.7939453125 KB. Since I had multiple images it took a lot of time to process them. Compressing them using the `image.jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat)!)` method solved all problems. Thank you [Mark Thormann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771593/mark-thormann) for suggesting the fix!